# Using MySQL and the Company Schema

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image]I can't figure out how to list the employee first name, last name, ssn, and the dependent’s name and relationship if a dependent exists. I need to use explicit join to list all employees with dependents including employees without dependents.

**Schema Name: Company**

**Table Name:** employee

Column Names: fname, minit, lname, ssn, bdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno

**Table Name:** dependent

Column Names: essn, dependent_name, sex, bdate, relationship

**Table Name:** dept_locations;

Column Names: dnumber, dlocation

**Table Name:** department

Column Names: dnumber, dname, mgrssn, mgrstartdate

**Table Name:** project

Column Names: pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum

**Table Name:** works_on

Column Names: essn, pno, hours

This is what I have but it doesn't work...so any advice would be great thanks!

```
SELECT a.fname, a.lname, a.ssn, b.dependent_name, b.relationship  
FROM `employee` a 
inner JOIN `dependent` b 
WHERE a.bdate=b.bdate;
```

Comment: Why are you comparing the birthdates of the employee and the dependent?

Comment: What do the tables other than `employee` and `dependent` have to do with this question?

Comment: I wasn't sure what to compare to get the result set for this. I'm new at sql. What should I be comparing?

Comment: Didn't you see the answer I posted?

Comment: What does being new at SQL have to do with it? It's just logical thinking about how the data is related.

Comment: @barmar I was just listing what was given to me to figure out the result set. But it seems like the other tables don't have to do anything with the question..or thats what i think

Answer (score 0):

Your query finds employees who have the same birthdate as a dependent. That's just a random coincidence, it doesn't mean they have any relationship.

You should be joining the tables based on the employee's SSN. I assume the `essn` column in `dependent` is the SSN of the employee they're a dependent of.

Also, joining conditions should be placed in the `ON` clause, not `WHERE` (although MySQL doesn't enforce this).

```
SELECT a.fname, a.lname, a.ssn, b.dependent_name, b.relationship  
FROM employee AS a
JOIN dependent AS b ON b.essn = a.ssn
```

Answer (score 0):

What Barmar suggested is pretty much correct...just missing one thing.  The OP needs to list employees with dependents and **without** dependents so a **left join** should be used.

```
select a.fname, a.lname, a.ssn, b.dependent_name, b.relationship  
  from employee a
  left join dependent b
    on b.essn = a.ssn;
```